# How can I split rows by day?

Tags: pandas

I have are many rows which indicate time they were created at

```
 'Fri Sep 19 17:27:16 blah blah' 

 'Fri Sep 19 17:14:28 blah blah'

 'Fri Sep 19 17:11:51 blah blah' 

          .
          .
          .
```

There are thousands of rows for a month and several dozen rows for each day

I'd like to put them into groups split by day. Which function should I use?

Comment: This post needs a lot more context so people can answer your question.  It's not clear how this relates to pandas - is your data in a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

```
itertools.groupby(rowlist, key=lambda row: row[0:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but assuming you have a column that has time values as strings and another as some arbritrary value, after loading you need to convert the 'date' to a datetime dtype and then you can group on date:

```
In [109]:
# load some data
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""Fri Sep 19 17:27:16,blah blah
Fri Sep 20 17:14:28,blah blah
Fri Sep 19 17:11:51,blah blah"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, names=['date', 'value'])
df

Out[109]:
                  date      value
0  Fri Sep 19 17:27:16  blah blah
1  Fri Sep 20 17:14:28  blah blah
2  Fri Sep 19 17:11:51  blah blah

In [110]:    
# convert the datetime string
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date     3 non-null datetime64[ns]
value    3 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 72.0+ bytes

In [113]:    
# group on the date
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['value'].max()

Out[113]:
2015-09-19    blah blah
2015-09-20    blah blah
Name: value, dtype: object
```

So the above uses [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) to convert the datetime str, I then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html#pandas.Series.dt.date) attribute of the 'date' column, here I call `max` just to show that it's distinguising between the differing dates.